# Array reference versus scalar reference

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this code segment to put together a hash of parameters which I will pass to a function. The hash value containing the IP address is supposed to be an array reference, but the function I'm passing my parameters to thinks it's a scalar reference.

My code is:

```
my $paramList = "ldap_ip_addresses=['192.168.1.100']|ldap_port=389|ldap_protocol=ldap";
my @paramTuples = split(/\|/, $paramList);

my %nasProps;
foreach my $paramTuple (@paramTuples) {
    my($key, $val) = split(/=/, $paramTuple, 2);

    # SetProperties can also take hashes or arrays
    my $eval_val = eval $val;
    if (ref($eval_val) =~ /ARRAY/) {
        $val = \$eval_val;
    }
    $nasProps{$key} = $val;
}
```

From the debugger, my parameter hash looks like this:

```
DB<18> x \%nasProps
0  HASH(0x303f8f0)
'ldap_authentication_type' => 'anonymous'
'ldap_ip_addresses' => REF(0x303fa70)
   -> ARRAY(0x8284eb8)
        0  '192.168.1.100'
'ldap_port' => 389
'ldap_protocol' => 'ldap'
```

It looks like a reference to an array so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, He's not trying to make an LDAP request yet; he's trying o parse a configuration in order to do so. Do you have reason to believe any of the modules returned by that query parse the configuration? I started going down the list and didn't see any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$eval_val` is already a reference to an array, there is no need to make a reference to the reference.  Change:

```
$val = \$eval_val;
```

to:

```
$val = $eval_val;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are unnecessarily taking the reference to a reference with

```
$val = \$eval_val;
```

You have established on the previous line that `$eval_val` is a reference to an array, so you can use it as it is without taking a reference to it again.

In addition, you should ignore the result of `ref $eval_val` except to check that it is *true* — i.e. `$eval_val` is a reference *of some sort*.

Your code should look more like this. You need to fall back to the original `$val` value only if `eval` returns `undef`, usually meaning that the string wasn't compilable code.

Note also that you should reserve capital letters for *global* Perl variables, such as package names. Lexical variable identifiers should contain only lower-case letters, decimal digits and underscores.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $param_list   = "ldap_ip_addresses=['192.168.1.100']|ldap_port=389|ldap_protocol=ldap";
my @param_tuples = split /\|/, $param_list;

my %nas_props;
for my $param_tuple (@param_tuples) {
    my ($key, $val) = split /=/, $param_tuple, 2;
    $nas_props{$key} = eval($val) // $val;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%nas_props;
```

**output**

```
{
  ldap_ip_addresses => ["192.168.1.100"],
  ldap_port         => 389,
  ldap_protocol     => "ldap",
}
```

Comment: Since you're cleaning up the code, probably better to avoid using `eval` unless needed: `$val = eval($val) if $val =~ /^\[/;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short alternative in functional style:

```
my %nasProps =
     map /\[/ ? eval : $_,
     split /[|=]/, $paramList;
```

However, it only works if you can guarantee that `=` is not included in any parameter values.